# Resetting enlighten progress bar

Tags: python

I'm using enlighten progress bars to keep track of some threads I've running. Each thread consists of a repeating for-loop, but I need the progress bar to reset between each for loop. So far the only way I have found to do this is by doing an update with a negative incr, this however messes with the time measurements. Is there any way of resetting or replacing a progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

I've looked around in the source code a bit and found that you can reset everything by setting .count = 0 and .start = time.time()

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can just create use `leave=False` when you create progress bar and close it when it's complete. Then create a new one to take its place.

```
import time
import enlighten


def run_loops(manager):

    ticks = manager.counter(total=100, desc='Ticks', unit='ticks', leave=False)
    tocks = manager.counter(total=20, desc='Tocks', unit='tocks', leave=False)

    for num in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
        print(num)
        ticks.update()
        if not num % 5:
            tocks.update()
    ticks.close()
    tocks.close()


with enlighten.get_manager() as manager:
    for num in range(10):
        run_loops(manager)
```

If you have multiple bars and need to maintain the positions, just use the `position` keyword for Counter.